# How to parse bbcode regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, bbcode

I have some trouble to find a regex.
I would like to parse all smilies except in bbcode [code].

for example :

```
[code] :D  :D  :D  :D  [/code] 
 :D :D :D
```

My regex must matching the three :D out of bbcode.

I tried  `(\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\])` to match the bbcode.

But I didn't find how except this block. I find on google how make an exception with `(^(\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\])*` but not working....

So my first question is : how match all smilley which look likes `:D` ? 
and how except a group (bbcode) in regex ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

This, I think, should do for you.

```
(:D)(?=[\s\S]*?\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\]+|(?![\s\S]*?\[\/code\]))
```

A sample implementation that converts all `:D`'s outside code-tags to links:

```
document.getElementById('tekt').value = document.getElementById('tekt').value.replace(/(:D)(?=[\s\S]*?\[code\][\s\S]*?\[\/code\]+|(?![\s\S]*?\[\/code\]))/igm,"");
```

[JSFiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/z5jova61/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I everyone, 
I have some problems to construct my regex.
Now I need to match all smilley which look like :D except between `<code></code>` and `<img />`

I don't understand the exception conception in a group. I found (?!bar).*

the regex :

```
(:D)(?=[\s\S]*?\<code\>[\s\S]*?\<\/code\>+|(?![\s\S]*?\<\/code\>))|(\<img (?!:D).+ \/>)
```

Test template

```
   :D :D :D

[quote="toto"]:D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D [/quote]

[spoiler="ygfdhy :D  :D  :D  :D "] :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D [/spoiler]

[hide] :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D [/hide]

<code>  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D </code>

<code>  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D  :D </code>

<img src="#" data-sceditor-emoticon=":D" alt=":D" title=":D" /> 

<img src=#" data-sceditor-emoticon=":D" alt=":D" title=":D" />
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fT2tQ5/1)

I have 2 problems :

- I can't no matching smilley in img tag
- I don't no match just one

Thank for your patience and your expertise

Comment: I found nearly the correct regex : `(:D)(?!((?=\w*[^<]*<(?!code)))|(?=\<img[^>]\>))` but i always match in the last img tag ... I don't understand why !  How I can loop on all img tag ?

Comment: I up my post, anyone have an issue to fix my problem ? I really is near the goal. Thank's !